# Select values that don't occur in mapping table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

```
================
| contacts     |
================
| id | name    |
================

================
| contact_map  |
================
| cid | lid    |
================

================
| contact_list |
================
| id | name    |
================
```

I need to find all the contacts that is not assigned to a list. `cid` in `contact_map` is `id` in `contacts` and `lid` in `contact_map` is `id` in `contact_list`.

Selecting the contacts with a `lid` is relatively easy, but I can't figure out how to select those without `lid`'s.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `not exists` or `not in`:

```
select c.*
from contacts c
where not exists (select 1
                  from contact_map cm
                  where cm.cid = c.id
                 );
```

If you want contacts not assigned to a *particular* list, then just include that information in the subquery:

```
select c.*
from contacts c
where not exists (select 1
                  from contact_map cm
                  where cm.cid = c.id and cm.lid = $lid
                 );
```

Comment: What do you call this type of query? A query with a sub query? Does it have a specific name? And thanks for the answer, will test now

Comment: These are examples of a correlated subquery in a `where` clause.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you actually need to use the `contact_list` table, since the `contact_map` table allows you to determine which contacts have been added to a list.  As an alternative to Gordon's answer, you can `LEFT JOIN` the `contacts` table to `contact_map` and retain any records which did *not* map to anything.

```
SELECT c.*
FROM contacts c LEFT JOIN contact_map cm
    ON c.id = cm.cid
WHERE cm.cid IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll have a look at that too. :)